# How to generate a permutation?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

My question is: given a list L of length n, and an integer i such that 0 <= i < n!, how can you write a function perm(L, n) to produce the ith permutation of L in O(n) time? What I mean by ith permutation is just the ith permutation in some implementation defined ordering that must have the properties:

1. For any i and any 2 lists A and B, perm(A, i) and perm(B, i) must both map the jth element of A and B to an element in the same position for both A and B.
2. For any inputs (A, i), (A, j) perm(A, i)==perm(A, j) if and only if i==j.

NOTE: this is not homework. In fact, I solved this 2 years ago, but I've completely forgotten how, and it's killing me. Also, here is a broken attempt I made at a solution:

```
def perm(s, i):
  n = len(s)
  perm = [0]*n
  itCount = 0
  for elem in s:
    perm[i%n + itCount] = elem
    i = i / n
    n -= 1
    itCount+=1
  return perm
```

ALSO NOTE: the O(n) requirement is very important. Otherwise you could just generate the n! sized list of all permutations and just return its ith element.

Comment: surely, you mean perm(L, i) and not perm(L, n)?

Comment: Well, first check for overflow. Then determine the first letter using mod. Then determine the second letter by recurring. Hope that helps.

Comment: Suppose you are trying to permute the list `(ABCDEF)`. So, the first letter will be A as long as your `i` is less than the number of permutations of `(BCDEF)`. Now subtract the number of permutations of `(BCDEF)` from `i`, and recurse on this smaller list.

Comment: Oh, and isn't your 2. violated if the A string contains multiple occurences of the same symbol?

Comment: @jlouis Actually, this would become an interesting, but quite harder question if instead the argument i was specified to range between 0 and the number of distinct permutations, and the function had to produce only distinct permutations.

Comment: jlouis: hmm, that's true. Well, suppose all elements are distinct.

Comment: Pascal Cuoq: the argument i *is* specified to be in between the range of 0 and the number of distinct permutations-1 i.e. n!. That requirement is right in the first line. And the function does have to produce only distinct permutations. That's what the second requirement says (or tries to say, as jlouis rightly pointed out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def perm(sequence, index):
    sequence = list(sequence)
    result = []
    for x in xrange(len(sequence)):
        idx = index % len(sequence)
        index /= len(sequence)
        result.append( sequence[idx] )
        # constant time non-order preserving removal
        sequence[idx] = sequence[-1]
        del sequence[-1]
    return result
```

Based on the algorithm for shuffling, but we take the least significant part of the number each time to decide which element to take instead of a random number. Alternatively consider it like the problem of converting to some arbitrary base except that the base name shrinks for each additional digit.

Comment: Iteration. Nice! I tried to do it iteratively, in much the same way as you, but failed horribly. I was missing the pop call.

Comment: Surely this isn't really O(n) time, since `pop` isn't O(1) time, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Could you use [factoradics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoradic)?  You can find an illustration via this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302371.aspx).

Update: I wrote an [extension of the MSDN algorithm](http://www.joshuaulrich.com/npri.c) that finds i'th permutation of n things taken r at a time, even if n != r.

Comment: Joshua, I made some small optimizations to the code (in PHP: http://codepad.org/8ZNZIR1g), I've also been trying to do the inverse (find the factoradic index given a certain permutation) but without success... You don't happen to know how to do that, do you? =)

Answer (score 2):

A computational minimalistic approach (written in C-style pseudocode):

```
function perm(list,i){
    for(a=list.length;a;a--){
        list.switch(a-1,i mod a);
        i=i/a;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Note that implementations relying on removing elements from the original list tend to run in O(n^2) time, at best O(n*log(n)) given a special tree style list implementation designed for quickly inserting and removing list elements.

The above code rather than shrinking the original list and keeping it in order just moves an element from the end to the vacant location, still makes a perfect 1:1 mapping between index and permutation, just a slightly more scrambled one, but in pure O(n) time.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I finally solved it. Before I read any answers, I'll post my own here.

```
def perm(L, i):
  n = len(L)
  if (n == 1):
    return L
  else:
    split = i%n
    return [L[split]] + perm(L[:split] + L[split+1:], i/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are n! permutations. The first character can be chosen from L in n ways. Each of those choices leave (n-1)! permutations among them. So this idea is enough for establishing an order. In general, you will figure out what part you are in, pick the appropriate element and then recurse / loop on the smaller L.

The argument that this works correctly is by induction on the length of the sequence. (sketch) For a length of 1, it is trivial. For a length of n, you use the above observation to split the problem into n parts, each with a question on an L' with length (n-1). By induction, all the L's are constructed correctly (and in linear time). Then it is clear we can use the IH to construct a solution for length n.