# ranking unranking combinations with limited duplicates (factoradic rank)

Tags: python, ranking

I need an algorithm which rank/unrank a combination with duplicates. What i need is for n numbers choose k numbers with upto r duplicates.

for example for the list with n(range) = 4, k(len_combination) = 3, r(max_repeats) =2

```
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 4)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 3)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 4)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 4)
(2, 3, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 4)
(3, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 4)
```

I would like the output as a the rank of the combination with (1,1,2) ranking lowest [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140505/computing-the-factoradic-rank-of-a-permutation-n-choose-k) provides me with an algorithm for permutations with duplicates and [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) gives me a method to calculate combinatorial rank without dupicates, my requirement is combinatorial rank with ***limited duplicates***

I am aware of itertools.product,Counting where my sequence is in the full list is not an option as I am dealing with n>100 what I need is a function like this. I am looking for a combinatoric calculation based solution.

```
def rank_seq(S,n,k,r):
    ##some kickass math calculations
return rank

print(rank_seq(2,2,4),4,3,2)) ##output 11
print(rank_seq(2,2,4),5,3,2)) ##output 16
print(rank_seq(2,2,4),6,3,2)) ##output 22
```

Comment: I don't understand fully whats your question

Comment: I want the lexicographical rank of each combination of the of the above sequence